# Algorithm: Function to resolve degrees to x,y for drawing SVG Pie Graphs

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, svg

I am working with SVG graphics to draw Pie Graphs. I am given the degrees a pie graph should be - eg 277 degrees - and the diameter - eg 200px - and I need to draw a circle of 277 degrees.

With SVG graphics I need to resolve that 277 degrees to a point where that circle will end.

I am not the greatest with math, so I have come up with a formula/javascript function that will allow me to take a degrees value & come up with a x,y point of where the circle will end.

**Will my Javascript function(at the bottom) correctly resolve a degrees to a correct point? Can you help me develop my algorithm to obtain the coordinate from a degree value?** Or maybe there is an existing algorithm I can use that I dont know about?

**My Algorithm:** (Which I require help with)
So the values I am given are: Circle Diameter: 200px, Circle size: 277 degrees.

- I require the point at which 277 ends when rotating around the point 0,0.
- 277 ends in the 1st quadrant which means I need to use sin *(is that correct?)*
- So the values I know now of the triangle are: the hypotenuse=100px(the radius), the angle=7 degrees(277-270).

  sin(7) = o/100;
  0.1219 = o/100;
  o      = 12.2;
- Therefore the y point is 12.2 (for my sakes 0,0 is the top left corner so its really midY-x = 100-12.2 = 87.8; (is that correct?)
- Now to determine the x pos, I use cos(is that correct?).

  cos(7) = a/100;
  a      = 99.25;
- Therefore the x point is 99.25 or 100-99.25=0.75;

So the x,y coordinate of 277 degrees is 0.75,87.8. Is that correct?

So in code this algorithm would be:

```
function resolveToPoint( deg, diameter )
{
    if ( deg <= 0)
        return 0;

    var x     = 0;
    var y     = 0;
    var angle = 0;
    var rad   = diameter/2;
    var midX  = rad;
    var midY  = rad;

    if (deg <= 90)
        angle = 90 - deg;
    else if (deg <= 180)
        angle = deg - 90;
    else if (deg <= 270)
        angle = deg - 180;
    else if (deg <= 360)
        angle = deg - 270;

    // Q: Will I ALWAYS use cos to determine the x & sin for the x NO MATTER what quadrant the angle is in??
    x = Math.cos(angle) * rad;
    y = Math.sin(angle) * rad;

    if (deg <= 90)
    {
        x = midX + x;
        y = midY - y;
    }
    else if (deg <= 180)
    {
        x = midX + x;
        y = midY + y;
    }
    else if (deg <= 270)
    {
        x = midX - x;
        y = midY + y;
    }
    else if (deg <= 360)
    {
        x = midX - x;
        y = midY - y;
    }

    return {mX: x, mY: y};
}
```

Then I'll use it in a SVG like so:

```
function outputPiegraph( point, rad, diameter )
{  
    var svg = '<svg width="%spx" height=""%spx" id='pie' style="background-color: green;">
    <path d="M%spx,%spx L%spx, %spx A%spx,"%spx 1 1,1 %spx,%spx z"
     fill="red" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" />"
</svg>';


    return sprintf(svg, diameter, diameter, point.mX, point.mY, rad, rad, rad, diameter);
}
```

Comment: Pie charts are almost always a bad idea.  Use a bar chart instead. http://4dpiecharts.com/2010/08/20/hello-world/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is simple conversion from polar to Cartesian coordinates:

```
function resolveToPoint(deg, diameter) {
    var rad = Math.PI * deg / 180;
    var r = diameter / 2;
    return {mX: r * Math.cos(rad), mY: r * Math.sin(rad)};
}
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinates#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates

Comment: I needed to change cos and sin to Math.cos and Math.sin respectively to get this to run...

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the unit circle, then the X-coordinate for a given (radians-based) angle is given by the cosine, likewise, the Y-coordinate is given by the sine. So, you can solve this easily as follows.

```
function resolveToPoint(deg, diameter) {  
  var radians = angle_in_degrees / 180 * Math.PI;
  var x = diameter / 2 * cos(radians);
  var y = diameter / 2 * sin(radians);

  return {mX : x, mY: y};
}
```